# Get width of element calling the jquery function dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using this function called [jquery-splitflap](https://github.com/zemax/jquery-splitFlap).

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="do-splitflap"></div>

<script>
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.do-splitflap')
                    .splitFlap();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

In the js/jquery file, how do I get the width of the div calling the function `.splitFlap()`? I am currently getting it using `this.divWidth = $(".do-splitflap").width();` and it works fine, but I don't want to put the className `do-splitflap` in the js file. Is there a way to get the width of the function caller dynamically? I'm pretty new to jquery/js.

The jquery parts of [the js file](https://github.com/zemax/jquery-splitFlap/blob/master/demo/js/jquery/jquery.splitflap.js) that I think is useful is

```
    /***************************************************************************
     * SplitFlap
     **************************************************************************/

    function SplitFlap(settings) {
        this.settings = settings;

        this.domObject = document.createElement('div');
        this.letters = new Array();

        $(this.domObject).addClass("splitflap");

        /* CODE I ADDED */
        this.divWidth = $(".do-splitflap").width();
    }
```

I believe this is where the function is defined, but I'm not 100% sure

```
            this.splitflap = new SplitFlap(settings);
            this.splitflap.build(text.length);
```

this is the [demo](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Airport-Like-Text-Flip-Animation-with-jQuery-CSS3-splitFlap/) of the jquery plugin.

Comment: Try `this.divWidth = $(".do-splitflap").css('width');`

Comment: It's what I did as written in my question. I think I've written my question too long. HAHAHAHA. What I want is for it to be dynamic. Not having to write the div name in the js file.

Comment: Actually you tried `$(".do-splitflap").width();` and it is not the same. You need to get the computed style of the element. Can you make fiddle etc? it will be easier to debug...

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not notice the difference. Btw, my code is working fine. I just want it to work dynamically and not place the div in the actual js file. I've updated the title so that people wont misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out where exactly to place the `.width` in the js file.

```
$.fn.splitFlap = function (options) {
...
    var divWidth = this.width();
...
        this.splitflap = new SplitFlap(settings, divWidth);
...
```

```
    /***************************************************************************
     * SplitFlap
     **************************************************************************/

    function SplitFlap(settings, divWidth) {
        this.settings = settings;

        this.domObject = document.createElement('div');
        this.letters = new Array();

        $(this.domObject).addClass("splitflap");

        /* CODE I ADDED */
        this.divWidth = divWidth;
    }
```

It's pretty basic jquery/js. I was just stupid earlier today.